# Python API connection issue/ not sure what they are asking

Tags: python, django, api, oauth

I am trying to connect to an [API](https://gimbal.com/doc/rest.html), and they gave the the following directions:

> The Gimbal APIs require your organization's server API key in the
>   AUTHORIZATION HTTP header. You can find your organization's server API
>   Key under Organizations.
>
> AUTHORIZATION: Token token=my_organization_server_api_key Important
>   Some Proximity APIs require OAuth access tokens. See below for more
>   information about OAuth.

I do have the server api key, rather my issue is how exactly do I access the server and make a connection with it.
I am currently using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and I am not exactly sure what commands are used to pass an HTTP header. Not to mention, what else needs to be done after the connection is made and/or will I be able to send data over in JSON format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [custom headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) part of the requests library.

Thus:

```
url = "https://manager.gimbal.com/api/" # Note you'll need to customize this
headers = {'Authorization': 'Token <server api key>'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Just enter the correct API endpoint in the `url` and substitute your server api key. Make sure you keep the rest of it, including `Token` in the value part.

Comment: Thanks! that was very helpful. Question though, when and why will I need to customize the URL?

Comment: The API I included is the root, but you'll want to add something to the end depending on the resource you're accessing. Thus, for example, if you want to use the Export Analytics part of the API, you'll change your url to `'https://manager.gimbal.com/api/export_analytics'`. (Export Analytics is just an example I found from your linked page)